# UIAlertView Background issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview

I Using a Uialertview in my class.

Here is my code

```
UIAlertView *alertView   = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
```

But the problem is when I press the ok button, the alert hides, but the black background is still there.

Does anyone have the answer for this?

Comment: you mean alertview is stucked on screen ?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot???

Comment: It's working fine at my end. Problem is something else .. show some more code so that we can help ...

Comment: Yes. its working for me also. As per "Vin"'s answer, just check whether any alter instance is alive on backgorund or not...

Comment: Are you sure you're running that code on the main thread?

Comment: Still not working guys ,  i think the alertView is in the main thread..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 UIAlertView * alertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
 [alertView show];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your Code `[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil @"message"` **should** `initWithTitle:@"message"`

Such Like,

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Your Message Body !!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
UIAlertView *alertView   = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertView show];
```